# Display table/table-cell - align one cell to the right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So, here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/8xpL78ow/ and I have a few issues I don't know exactly how to solve:

**a)** I want the buttons to be aligned to the right side and always stay in one line (don't collapse under other button like in 'very long folder name' example ). If a use `float: right` on `.btn-group` div, it's ok, but here's my second point:

**b)** I want to text fill all of remaining horizontal space.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I updated my answer, please take a look.

Comment: Yup, you're the man! Now it works exactly as I wanted. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try something like this.

```
#folder-panel .btn-group {
    text-align: right;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
#folder-panel .btn {
    float: none;
}
```

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/xe208rxs/

Since you are using Bootstrap, you need to make sure that your CSS rules are specific enough to take effect.

I added an ID to your `.container` block, and then modified the `.btn` rules to set `float: none`.  This means the buttons will now be inline elements.

If you do not want to use and ID, then you will have to make sure that you duplicate the selectors in Bootstrap to override the CSS rules that you need to alter.

Set `text-align: right` to `.btn-group` and the buttons will align to the right.
Finally, set `white-space: nowrap` and this will prevent the icons from wrapping.

Note: You could try setting a min-width value, but that is less flexible.

Comment: It's not bad idea, but I would like to avoid using min-width since in some items I can have 3 or 4 buttons inside btn-group, therefore the width of this element must adjust itself

Comment: Also, i think it could easily done by using flexbox, but I need table/table-cell fallback for browsers not supporting flexbox anyway :/

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `pull-right` option for your button group by this way they will float right. And also use grid section if needed to seperate the buttons and text content.

```
 <div class="container">

    <div class="list-group folders-list">
        <a class="list-group-item active" href="#">
            Folder 1
        </a>
        <a class="list-group-item table" href="#">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <span class="folder-name table-cell">Very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very long folder name</span></div>
            <div class="pull-right btn-group btn-group-xs table-cell" role="group" aria-label="action buttons">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a class="list-group-item table" href="#">
            <span class="folder-name table-cell">Folder 3</span>
            <div class="pull-right btn-group btn-group-xs table-cell" role="group" aria-label="action buttons">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a class="list-group-item table" href="#">
            <span class="folder-name table-cell">Folder 4</span>
            <div class="pull-right btn-group btn-group-xs table-cell" role="group" aria-label="action buttons">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a class="list-group-item table" href="#">
            <span class="folder-name table-cell">Folder 5</span>
            <div class="pull-right btn-group btn-group-xs table-cell" role="group" aria-label="action buttons">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

</div> <!-- /container -->
```

Comment: `pull-right` will work nicely except for the first line with the long label.  In this case, the icons stack vertically.  But, adding a min-width value to the `.btn-group` will fix the issue, but then the icons may not be flushed exactly to the right, but it depends on how particular the designer is.  I don't use Bootstrap much to it is good to learn about the `pull-right` class.

Comment: Yeah totally agree with you, for the first line it won't work. But as you said we can use either `min-width` or separate the label and the button group in a grid system using "columns" (`col-md`, `col-sm`, etc...). And of course, it's depending on the need and flexibility of the user :)